# how to send and get data in rest api and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

my codes :

interface :

```
@POST("login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<User> UserLogin(@Field("username") String username,@Field("password") String password);
```

login_activity:

```
Call<User> call = apiInterface.UserLogin(username,password);
```

rest api php :

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$content = json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
username =$content['username'];
password =$content['password'];
```

But it does not work.
what is problem?

```
result : null
```

Comment: in server side should be get data from post method same as 
`username =$_POST['username'];`
`password =$_POST['password'];`

Answer (score 1):

As @Morteza Jalambadani pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026057/how-to-send-and-get-data-in-rest-api-and-retrofit#comment91002283_52026057) on your post, you're sending FormUrlEncoded data not JSON. So, you need to receive the data in server script like below,

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
   username = $_POST['username'];
   password = $_POST['password'];
   // do whatever you want with the data received from client
}
```

If you really want to send JSON data from client to server, you need to do following changes.

Create a model class (I'll create `Login` class here for demonstration)

```
public class Login {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  public Login(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  // getter and setter methods if you want 
}
```

In API interface class remove `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation and change `UserLogin()` method parameters.

```
@POST("login")
Call<User> UserLogin(@Body Login data);  // @Body annotation from retrofit2.http.Body package
```

Now in your Activity class do the following changes.

```
String username = "user_name_entered_by_user";
String password = "password_entered_by_user";

Login data = new Login(username, password);

// pass data parameter to UserLogin() method
Call<User> call = apiInterface.UserLogin(data);
```

And the server script is same as you posted in your question.

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$content = json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
username =$content['username'];
password =$content['password'];
```